# TCP how do I relay the packets from my client to the server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, tcp

So I am working on creating my own proxy server for my game server.
Whats happening so far is that I try to connect to my Terraria server and it says 
`Connecting..`
 Then I start my server application which accepts incoming requests on that specific IP & port and it prompts a MessageBox saying`"Connected"` and then the game goes from "Connecting..." to "Connecting to server..." but it gets stuck there, this is most likely because I am not redirecting the traffic from my proxy server to my server.. Right?

I've been trying to `.Write()` to the stream but I think I am writing to the wrong stream, do I write to the stream that accepts connections or do I create a new stream for outgoing traffic?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static IPAddress remoteAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        public TcpListener remoteServer = new TcpListener(remoteAddress, 7777);
        public TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);

        public TcpClient RemoteClient = new TcpClient("terraria.novux.ru", 7777);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnListen_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (StartServer())
            {
                client = remoteServer.AcceptTcpClient();
                MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                var receivedBuffer = new byte[1024];

                //Should I write to this one instead?
                var clientStream = client.GetStream();

                var stream = RemoteClient.GetStream();

                while (client.Connected)
                    if (client.Connected)
                        if (client.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
                        {
                            receivedBuffer = new byte[1024];
                            stream.Write(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);
                        }
            }
        }

        private bool StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                remoteServer.Start();
                MessageBox.Show("Server Started...");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, you would need to write to client.GetStream();

Comment: Seems as if that doesnt let me connect still

Comment: could u pls share ur client code as well (where client connects to server) ?

Comment: That's all their is, It's listening for a connection on that IP and port, and I've changed it to where when I join my Terraria server, windows redirects the hostname to localhost.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than this. You need one TcpClient that will handle communication (send and receive messages) with the remote server and you will need a TcpListener that will handle communication with the clients. When the TcpListener will receive the message it will forward it to the TcpClient that will send it to the remote server. When the TcpClient receives a message from the remote server it will forward it to the TcpListener that will send it to its connected client.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified implementation could look like this.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartTcpListener("localhost", 9000);
    }

    private static byte[] SendReceiveRemoteServer(string host, int port, byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a TcpClient.
            // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
            // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
            // combination.
            var client = new TcpClient(host, port);

            // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
            //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

            var stream = client.GetStream();

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Sent to server: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));

            // Receive the TcpServer.response.

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            var bytes = new byte[256];
            var allBytes = new List<byte>();
            var i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
            while (i != 0)
            {
                allBytes.AddRange(bytes);

                bytes = new Byte[256];
                i = stream.DataAvailable ? stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) : 0;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Received from server: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));

            // Close everything.
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();

            return allBytes.ToArray();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
        return new byte[0];
    }

    private static void StartTcpListener(string host, int port)
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            var ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
            var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                var stream = client.GetStream();

                // Buffer for reading data
                var bytes = new Byte[256];
                var allBytes = new List<byte>();
                var i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while (i != 0)
                {
                    allBytes.AddRange(bytes);

                    bytes = new Byte[256];
                    i = stream.DataAvailable ? stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) : 0;
                }

                if (allBytes.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received from client: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(allBytes.ToArray()));

                    var received = SendReceiveRemoteServer("localhost", 11000, allBytes.ToArray());

                    // Send back a response.
                    stream.Write(received, 0, received.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent to client: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));
                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
    }
}
```

Although improvements should be made:

- make it async
- make it work with multiple TcpClients at the same time

Comment: Oh, yeah I was doing pretty much the same thing I just couldnt figure out how to send the data back, I'll read through your example a bit more.

Comment: After sending sending back what I receive, it's not getting any more data for some reason

Comment: In this example the connection is closed after the message is send, you need to keep the connection open and check if there is any new data coming through.

Comment: Yeah I know, I changed that and it gets to the point where it should read but it just stops there.